# sublime text 3 package control freeze on install

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext, freeze, package-control

Sys info:

- Ubuntu 14.04, 64bit

Fresh install Sublime Text 3083 (http://www.sublimetext.com/3) then followed directions here:
https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3

Tried both "simple" and "manual". Sublime just freeze on restart. By freeze I mean Sublime start to fade in darker color and doesn't respond to input. After about 2s,the option "wait" or "force quit" is prompted.

Here is what I've tested:

1. For the "simple" method, sublime freeze on this step:

   ```
   print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
   ```
2. For the "manual" method. First, `Package Control.sublime-package` is put into `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed\ Packages/`. Then sublime is restarted. This leads to a new file `0_package_control_loader.sublime-package` being generated in the "*Installed Packages*" folder, followed by the same freeze described above.
3. The freeze goes away if I delete the `Package Control.sublime-package` file in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed\ Packages/`, and restart Sublime.
4. I also tried `sudo apt-get purge sublime-text` and reinstall it.

Thanks in advance if there's anyone who could help me with this :)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. The issue is [resolved](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/988) by Will in the latest updates in Package Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue affecting many users. See https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/988

UPDATE:
The problem has been resolved by packagecontrol developer

Comment: Thanks, Eugene, for the reference to the original GitHub ripo. Should've checked that. And kudos to Will for the swift response to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Manual Installation

If for some reason the console installation instructions do not work for you (such as having a proxy on your network), perform the following steps to manually install Package Control:

1. Click the Preferences > Browse Packages… menu and close sublime text 3
2. Browse up a folder and then into the Installed Packages/ folder
3. Download Package Control.sublime-package and copy it into the Installed Packages/ directory
4. go to this address https://github.com/wbond/package_control/blob/master/Package%20Control.sublime-settings
   copy the code
5. open the copied downloaded "Package Control.sublime-package" in Installed Package (double click the package)
6. edit the file Package Control.sublime-settings in downloaded Package Control.sublime-package and replace the code that you copied in github
7. save and close Package Control.sublime-package
8. start Sublime Text 3 and wait to install package and restart